Flutter-Firebase Production Ready Apps rules
So i am making a Flutter application which is going to be in production so is there anything to be checked while creating bundle for uploading it in playstore,
In my case i am integrating Firebase into my application for crash analytics and for firebase cloud messaging. so i am added google-services.json file in android app folder in my project. So is it right way or is there another way ???
I downloaded the google-services.json file and put in the android app in the flutter project so is it right way. when producing aab file is there will be any problem ? is malicious hackers can go through .json file or what?

The values in the google-services.json are not an authorization mechanism, but rather just a configuration that allows the SDK to find your Firebase project on the server. See the question I linked for more details on this.
